# Inconsistent margins/spacing with Material UI Accordion

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using Material UI Accordion for creating a filter menu.

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfn0.png) on some devices whereas it looks likes [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92307968/141370635-15461171-305d-4369-bdca-dbd90c48c4aa.png) on other devices with different dimensions even though the margins between the items are the same and uses the same code. On resizing the dimensions of the screen, the inconsistency changes.

How to fix this inconsistency with the spacing between each filter item?

Here's my file `FilterAccordion.tsx`:

```
<Box className={classes.accordionRoot}>
  <Accordion style={{ boxShadow: "none" }} defaultExpanded={true}>
    <AccordionSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMore style={{ fill: "#d3d3d3" }} />}>
      <div className={classes.verticalrootcontainer}>
        <Icon
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          style={{
            fill: "#d3d3d3",
            width: "2rem",
            marginRight: "1rem",
            transform: "scale(3)",
            zIndex: -1,
          }}
        />
        <Typography
          variant="body1"
          className={`titleAquire ${classes.title}`}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </AccordionSummary>
    <AccordionDetails>
      <div className={classes.listRoot}>
        {Object.keys(groupByPacks).map((item, index) => {
          let checked = isChecked(item);
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={`${classes.list} ${
                checked ? classes.selected : ""
              }`}
              onClick={() => handleOnCheck(item)}>
              <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.item}>
                {item}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.item}>
                {groupByFilteredPacks[item]
                  ? groupByFilteredPacks[item]?.length
                  : 0}
              </Typography>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </AccordionDetails>
  </Accordion>
</Box>
```

And the CSS file:

```
  accordionRoot: {
    "& .MuiAccordion-root": {
      background: "transparent",
    },
    "& .MuiAccordionDetails-root": {
      padding: "0px",
    },
    "& .MuiAccordionSummary-root": {
      padding: "0px",
      marginBottom: "-1rem",
    },
    "& .MuiCollapse-entered": {
      marginTop: "1rem",
    },
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: "18px",
    color: theme.on.dark,
  },
  verticalrootcontainer: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  list: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop: "0.2rem",
    padding: "0.2rem 0.5rem",
    cursor: "pointer",
    "&:first-child": {
      marginTop: 0,
    },
  },
  item: {
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    color: theme.on.dark,
    opacity: "30%",
  },
  selected: {
    background: theme.on.dark,
    "& p": {
      color: theme.darkMode.light,
      opacity: "100%",
    },
  },
  listRoot: {
    width: "100%",
  },
```